# off-grid data center

Tags: solar-cell, data, system

My final project is to design an off-grid solar system for a data center at our university,it's a small one with a 9000 btu air condition for cooling.

My question is about cooling !!

Most important issue in data center is cooling, and if I want my design to be good , I have to take the air condition in my calculation but air conditions needs a high ampere at the beginning, is it ok for a stand alone pv system to make it work fine? or should I figure something else for cooling?

also can someone tell me the steps to do it ?

Thank you

Comment: Just to help you along, your question is way too broad. You need to narrow it down and show some calculations. Like show your proposed solar power system and its nominal output. Then show an air-con system and work out its power requirements. You might find you answer your own question!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is extremely broad, so I will give a correspondingly broad answer.

Generally speaking, an off-grid PV system comprises four major components:

PV panel array → Storage system → Inverter → Load

Sizing each of these components follows a few basic rules, keeping in mind that both the power available from the panels and the power consumed by the load are variable, and not correlated with each other.

For the panels, you need to know things like the average amount of power available, the peak power available and the longest expected interval with no significant power available (e.g., a string of cloudy days). Obviously, the average power must meet or exceed the average power consumed by the load, after taking into account all of the inefficiencies of the various power-conversion stages. The peak power must be capable of recharging a nearly-depleted storage system in a reasonable amount of time.

For the load, you need to know the average power consumed and the peak power consumed, and perhaps some information about the duty cycle and duration of the demand peaks.

The storage subsystem needs to have enough total capacity to supply the average power for the duration of the longest period without input power. It also needs to be able to supply the peak power required by the load. Normally, this is implemented as an array of batteries, but if the load peaks are very high and/or very short, they might be augmented with ultracaps as well.

In any case, the inverter needs to be capable of supplying the peak load, no matter how short its duration is.

As you note, if high load peaks might add unnecessary expense to the storage and inverter systems, it might be worthwhile to investigate other ways of achieving the application goal (cooling) through other mechanisms that have less-demanding electrical needs.

For example, there are heat-driven refrigeration systems (normally used in campers and cabins, powered by propane) that could be driven by solar thermal energy directly, rather than by electricity. Passive cooling, using the panels to shade the equipment, along with a chimney to create a draft, could help reduce the heat load as well.